# Basic Auth with jetty8 is not working

Tags: java, xml, jetty, basic-authentication

I tried to configure jetty to use a basic http authentication. I followed some tutorials but it's still not working. 
Here's what i did:
First I configured a HashLoginService "Test Realm" in jetty.xml.

/etc/jetty8/jetty.xml:

```
...
<Call name="addBean">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
      <Set name="name">Test Realm</Set>
      <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/realm.properties</Set>
      <Set name="refreshInterval">0</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
...
```

After that I defined the user-roles and the login-config in webdefault.xml

/etc/jetty8/webdefault.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>A Protected Page</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
    <role-name>moderator</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>Test Realm</realm-name>
</login-config>


<security-role>
  <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Finally I edited the /etc/realm.properties file:

```
test: test,user
```

When I try to access the website a login window appears. If I enter the test-user the authentification window will show up again without any error message. Is there anything else I need to configure?
I want to secure the whole server including all webapps. So it would be nice to use only .xml configuration files.

Thanks in advance,
Robert